# How to specify a Composite Primary Key while defining a Custom Interface as a JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two Entity class with below attributes:

```
class Parent {
    @Id
    string columnA;

    string columnB;
}

class Child {
    //confused here: ManyToOne with Parent class

    string columnC;
    string columnD;
}
```

I want SQL Tables as below:

1. Parent ( columnA(Primary Key), columnB )
2. Child ( columnA(Foreign Key), columnC, columnD ) where,

   - primary key = (columnA, columnC) and,
   - (Child -> ManyToOne -> Parent) relationship.

Question1: How can I create the correct Entity class for the Child?

Question2: I want to have a childRepository interface that extends JpaRepository. I am confused, how to specify the composite primary key?

```
public interface childRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, 'What to write here?'>{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question-1: It depends on your business logic.
Question-2: Create new class in order to store child entity's ids

```
@Embeddable
public class ChildId implements Serializable{

   private String columnA;
   private String columnC;

   // getters and setters
}
```

In your child class:

```
@EmbeddedId
private ChildId childId;

@MapsId(value = "columnA")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "columnA")
private Parent parent;
```

In your ChildRepository:

```
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, ChildId>{}
```

PS: you can apply other ways according to business logic

Comment: whenever I save the parent entity, child entity should also get saved. Also whenever I fetch parent entity, child entity should also be present in it. Is that possible?

Comment: 1. Use cascading in parent entity side in @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   (search other cascade types: persist, merge, detach, refresh, remove)                                          2. Use eager fetching for this purpose.